# Saving plots in R within a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

Yesterday I upgraded R to version 3.0.0 and ggplot2 to version 0.9.3.1 (and made a few minor changes to my script).  Now I am getting errors when attempting to save plots - unfortunately the error is not reproduced with a smaller dataframe, so I have included code to generate one of the same size.

```
library("ggplot2")

# Create data frame
# Time interval ID (x)
bin.ts.avg <- as.data.frame(rep(1:18, 31))
names(bin.ts.avg) <- "x"
# Time (sequence of 10 minuter intervals between 7am and 10am)
tt.month.bins <- seq(from=as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 GMT"), to=as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 GMT") + 60*60*24*31, by="10 mins")
tt.month.bins <- tt.month.bins[-length(tt.month.bins)]
temp <- as.numeric(format(tt.month.bins, "%H"))
ind <- which(temp >=7 & temp <= 9)  
tt.month.bins <- tt.month.bins[ind]
bin.ts.avg$dep <- tt.month.bins
# Value (with some NA)
bin.ts.avg$tt <- runif(558, min=2.5, max=5)
bin.ts.avg$tt[trunc(runif(200, min=1, max=558))] <- NA
# Day
bin.ts.avg$depday <- rep(1:31, each=18)

for (i in 1:2){
  if (1){
    hist(rnorm(100))
    dev.print(file="MyHist.png",device=png, bg="white",  width=640, height=352) 

    p <- ggplot(bin.ts.avg, aes(x, tt)) + geom_point() +geom_line() + facet_grid(.~depday)
    p <- p + ggtitle("10 minute averages")+ xlab("Hour") + ylab("Values")    
    p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(min(bin.ts.avg$x), max(bin.ts.avg$x)), labels=c("7", "10"))
    print(p)  
    dev.print(file="MyGGPlot.png",device=png, bg="white",  width=640, height=352) 
  }
}
```

On running this script, I receive the following error message:

> Error in UseMethod("depth") :    no applicable method for 'depth'
>   applied to an object of class "NULL"

However, if I run the script line by line everything runs okay (picture below).   [image: How the ggplot should look] Now if I change the for loop and use dev.copy and ggsave instead of dev.print as below

```
for (i in 1:2){
  if (1){
    hist(rnorm(100))
    dev.copy(file="MyHist.png",device=png, bg="white",  width=640, height=352) 
    dev.off()

    p <- ggplot(bin.ts.avg, aes(x, tt)) + geom_point() +geom_line() + facet_grid(.~depday)
    p <- p + ggtitle("10 minute averages")+ xlab("Hour") + ylab("Values")    
    p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(min(bin.ts.avg$x), max(bin.ts.avg$x)), labels=c("7", "10"))
    print(p)  
    ggsave(filename="MyGGPlot.png")
  }
}
```

On attempting to open "MyGGPlot.png" using Paint, I receive an error message stating

```
A sharing violation occurred while accessing <filename>
```

I run the script using RStudio version 0.97.449.
Any ideas on what I need to change in order to save current plots?

Comment: Within each loop, try opening a device (e.g. `png()`), and give a unique file name, before your plot. Then close the device at the end of the loop with `dev.off()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple of points

Use `graphics.off()` after `dev.copy`. This will close all graphics devices. You could also call `dev.off()` twice (but `graphics.off()` is a wrapper that will basically call `dev.off()` sufficient times to close all graphics devices

`ggsave` doesn't require a `print`ed object (this is **not** a case where [FAQ 7.22](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f) is relevant).

The default is the value of `last_plot` which is the last `ggplot` object created, modified or printed. So creating `p` is sufficient for 
`ggsave('filname.png')` to  save that object.

```
for (i in 1:2){
  if (1){
    hist(rnorm(100))
    dev.copy(file="MyHist.png",device=png, bg="white",  width=640, height=352) 
    graphics.off()

    p <- ggplot(bin.ts.avg, aes(x, tt)) + geom_point() +geom_line() + facet_grid(.~depday)
    p <- p + ggtitle("10 minute averages")+ xlab("Hour") + ylab("Values")    
    p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(min(bin.ts.avg$x), max(bin.ts.avg$x)), labels=c("7", "10"))
   # no need to print p
   ggsave(filename="MyGGPlot.png")
   # note specifying p is redundant but explicit.
   # ggsave(filename = 'MyGGplot.png', plot = p)
  }
}
```