# "A sharing violation occurred" when outputting PNG from R

Tags: r, windows, permissions

I'm outputting a PNG from R:

```
png(filename = "X:/public/my_file.png", width = 1800, height = 1900, units = 'px')
```

And when I try to open it, I get the error:

```
A sharing violation occurred
```

Is this specifically an issue within R, or if it's a permissions issue with Windows?  I have access to the folder I'm outputting to so I'm really not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: Without a detailed example of the code... maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161852/saving-plots-in-r-within-a-loop

Comment: Are you calling `dev.off()` to close the graphics device after you draw the plot? It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.